# Eigen matrix multiplication performance using row-major Matrices

Tags: c++, eigen

I was profiling my code to get better performance when I ran into the following issue.
The following code randoms two matrices and multiplies them to get the same result in different ways and  with different performance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include <chrono>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

class Timer {
protected:
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1_;
  string message_;

public:
  Timer(){t1_ = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();}
  virtual ~Timer() {}

  void time(const char* msg) {
    auto t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cerr << msg << ": "
              << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1_)
                         .count() << " ms\n";
    t1_ = t2;

  }
};

typedef Matrix<float, -1, -1, RowMajor> MatrixXRMf;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Timer timer;

  MatrixXf A = MatrixXf::Random(10, 4096);
  MatrixXf B = MatrixXf::Random(4096, 10000);
  timer.time("random");

  MatrixXf C1 = A * B;
  timer.time("col-maj 1");

  MatrixXf C2 = (B.transpose() * A.transpose());
  C2.transposeInPlace();
  timer.time("col-maj 2");


  MatrixXRMf A_rm = A;
  MatrixXRMf B_rm = B;
  timer.time("assignment");

  MatrixXRMf C3 = A_rm * B_rm;
  timer.time("row-maj 1");

  MatrixXRMf C4 = (B_rm.transpose() * A_rm.transpose());
  C4.transposeInPlace();
  timer.time("row-maj 2");

  cout << "C3 == C1: " << C3.isApprox(C1) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The printed result is

```
random: 352 ms
col-maj 1: 130 ms
col-maj 2: 72 ms
assignment: 981 ms
row-maj 1: 62 ms
row-maj 2: 80 ms
C3 == C1: 1
```

Why is C1 multiplication slower than C3?
If one would do C1 multiplication several times that could lead to a serious performance toll.

Eigen: 3.3.4
Compiler: GCC 5.4
OS: Ubuntu16

EDIT:
Compilation flags: -O3 -mavx -mfma -fopenmp

EDIT:
I have two ubuntu16 machines that reproduce this behavior
and another ubuntu16 machine that doesn't reproduce it

Comment: Please use compile-time vectors (e.g., `VectorXf`) for vectors instead of general matrices. More precisely, `A` should be a `VectorXf` to activate the dedicated matrix-vector kernels.

Comment: I understand your comment but MatrixXf::Random(1, 4096) was used only to simplify the question. my original problem occured with real matrices, for example, MatrixXf::Random(50, 4096) or more where I get the same performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I get completely different results, OSX, 2.6Ghz Haswell (trubo-boost off):

```
# gcc-7 -O3  -mavx -mfma
random: 498 ms
col-maj 1: 26 ms
col-maj 2: 69 ms
assignment: 674 ms
row-maj 1: 50 ms
row-maj 2: 57 ms

# Apples's clang 8 -O3  -mavx -mfma
random: 478 ms
col-maj 1: 25 ms
col-maj 2: 66 ms
assignment: 666 ms
row-maj 1: 55 ms
row-maj 2: 75 ms
```

And after using `RowVectorXf` (resp. `VectorXf`) for `A`, `C1`, `A_rm`, `C3` (resp. `C2`, `C4`), and removing the useless `transposeInPlace`, I get:

```
# Apples's clang 8 -O3  -mavx -mfma
random: 472 ms
col-maj 1: 12 ms
col-maj 2: 11 ms
assignment: 673 ms
row-maj 1: 13 ms
row-maj 2: 11 ms
```

EDIT: after using the edited question (e.g., `A = MatrixXf::Random(10, 4096);`), I still cannot reproduce, even using gcc-5 as in the question:

```
random: 482 ms
col-maj 1: 60 ms
col-maj 2: 80 ms
assignment: 676 ms
row-maj 1: 79 ms
row-maj 2: 85 ms
```

Comment: You are correct, on Mac I got the same results as you did. Currently, I have two Ubuntu 16 machines that I've managed to reproduce the "bad" results and another machine that does not. I forgot to mention that I've used -fopenmp flag and after investigating further I realized that it only occurs when this flag is used

Comment: any clue what could be the difference between the machines that reproduced and those who didn't?

Comment: If you have hyper-threaded CPUs on Linux you must limit the number of threads to the number of physical cores, e.g., by setting the respective environment variable: `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4`